# Can't find the specified file

Tags: python-3.x, operating-system

I'm trying to convert every file in a folder from mp4 to mp3 using the libary pydub but when i do it return the error `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`. I'm not sure how i can be more specific about the file.

Here's my code:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
import os
import os.path

folder = 'C:/Users/Magnus/Desktop/test/'

videos = []

for file in [f for f in os.listdir(folder) \
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folder, f))]:
    AudioSegment.from_file(folder + file).export(folder + file, format="mp3")
```

Inside of `C:/Users/Magnus/Desktop/test/` i have files that look like this `M83_-_Bibi_The_Dog_(Audio).mp4`

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Magnus\Desktop\youtube-playlist-downloader.py", line 64, in <module>
    AudioSegment.from_file(os.path.join(folder, file)).export(os.path.join(folder, file), format="mp3")
  File "C:\Users\Magnus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 505, in from_file
    p = subprocess.Popen(conversion_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\Magnus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\Magnus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 1224, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

also replacing `folder + file` with `os.path.join(folder, file)` doesn't work either

Comment: Why are you concatenating when you properly join in the previous line?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams if i print(folder+file) i get this `C:/Users/Magnus/Desktop/test/M83_-_Bibi_The_Dog_(Audio).mp4` which looks right

Comment: Could you please paste full stack trace?

Comment: @UbdusSamad Done

Comment: You seem not to have ffmpeg correctly installed. The `FileNotFound` error is not for the audio file you are converting but for the external tool that pydub is trying to call via `subprocess.Popen`

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I have now downloaded ffmpeg and made a path, but it still doesn't seem to work. ffmpeg works fine in the terminal i can convert a file just fine, but the python script still doesn't work. Still same error message and also saying `Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work`

Comment: do one thing, split the last statement into two parts to pin point the origin of the error! Something like z= AudioSegment.from_file(folder + file) and then in a new line z.export(folder + file, format="mp3") and then find out which line is exactly causing this error?

Comment: It seems that it's the first line i.e `sample = AudioSegment.from_file(os.path.join(folder, file))`

Comment: I don't know man, you should try to debug (or analyze) that pydub/audio_segment.py yourself and try to find some luck, or maybe try running this audio segment command alone without this os.file junk to try if that command works alone or not?

Comment: or maybe purge your pydub installation and try reinstalling it again!

Comment: Turns out i had to restart my computer. Everything seems to work now. Thanks for you help @UbdusSamad !

Comment: Can't stop laughing! Really? Was that a mounting problem or something?

Comment: I don't know what it was. But i definitely needed ffmpeg. I don't know if the path didn't load or something. At least it works ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error.I was using anaconda.

This error doesn't look like a file error but due to either :

- ffmpeg not being installed.
  (or)
- ffmpeg not being added to the environment variable.(Along with FFmpeg even your python.exe and conda.exe should be in the env variable)

Do the following steps :

On Windows:

- Download and extract libav/ffmpeg from Windows binaries.
- Add the libav /bin folder to your PATH environment variable.
- pip install pydub

You can use this for reference : https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub

Comment: This is where you can download the zip file for ffmpeg : https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/

Also this link is useful if you don't know how to add them to the system path : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pHR3ttH5t-w&t=1s